# Ducktyping implicit conversion in Scala

Tags: scala, type-conversion

Is it possible to have a duck-typing style conversion where a converter will accept an arbitrary object and will try to convert it to the destination type?

```
case class RequiredFields(name: String, surname: String)
case class Person(name: String, surname: String, age: Option[Int])
implicit def arbitraryToPerson(object: ????): Person = Person(object.name, object.surname, None)
```

Arbitrary object doesn't have to be related to RequriedField class in any way, just the fields must exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can combine structural typing and implicit conversions. Like so:

```
type RequiredFields = { 
  def name: String
  def surname: String
}

case class NotAPerson(name: String, surname: String)
case class Person(name: String, surname: String, age: Option[Int])

implicit def arbitraryToPerson(o: RequiredFields): Person = Person(o.name, o.surname, None)

val p:Person = NotAPerson("oh", "my")
```

Are you sure that's a good idea, though? I think the much better pattern here would be to define a type class with the required fields. Have you considered that?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're looking for a trait:

```
trait Nameable {
  def name: String
  def surname: String
}
case class Person(name: String, surname: String, age: Option[Int]) extends Nameable
implicit def arbitraryToPerson(variable: Nameable): Person = Person(variable.name, variable.surname, None)
```

You can think of a trait like an interface. A characteristic of Scala traits is that they also accept implementations of its methods.

Classes extending this trait will need to implement the methods `name` and `surname`. In this case, the only valid Nameable parameter would be a Person. Having more classes that extend the trait would allow for some sort of polymorphism, making this implicit actually useful.

**EDIT**
From your comment and negative, just to point out that you can call your traits however you like. In your case, something like `Nameable` could work. It doesn't mean that there's a hierarchy, but that your object fulfils certain conditions, such as implementing those methods. Classes can extend more than one trait in Scala, using the `with` keyword.

```
case class Dog(name: String, surname: String) extends Animal with Nameable
```

In this case, your dog would be an animal, but you can enforce the implementation of the Nameable methods by extending the trait.

Comment: Not really, I do not want to have class hierarchy.  I have an arbitrary object that might or MIGHT NOT be a superclass of person. eg. the conversion would work on ALL objects that have fields regardless of their inheritance.

Comment: @ArtursVacans Then you need to change the type Human for whatever type you want to use as a source of the data to create a Person. And from that moment on, you will be able to send that type to a parameter of type Person.

Comment: I presume this would work, but I would not really want to pollute my destination entity with extra traits :/

Answer (score 0):

As hasumedic answered you probably want to use a trait.

If for some reason you don't want to use a trait (you don't have control over the package objects that are being sent to you etc) you can also use reflection to get the fields. (I don't actually know if this is a good idea, but my best guess is that it isn't)

```
case class RequiredFields(name: String, surname: String)
val rF = new RequriedFields("Hey", "yo")
val method = rF.getClass.getDeclaredMethod("name")
```

Then you get your value by invoking the getter for that field that scala makes for you

```
scala> val x = method.invoke(rF).asInstanceOf[String]
x: String = Hey
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can do ducktyping driven conversion in the following way:

```
implicit def convertToPerson(obj: {def name(value: String): String; def surname(): String}): Person = {
    Person(obj.name, obj.surname, None)
}
```

Comment: You can, but as Lutz observes, you shouldn't. At least, I would hope no one would resort to this except under quite unusual circumstances.